# Not able to codesign GDB on MAC OSX Yosemite

Tags: macos

I installed gdb using the command: `brew install gdb`. To use gdb it requires me to codesign it. I created a user  system certificate as given on the website : https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingOnDarwin. But when I run the command `$ codesign -s gdb-cert gdb`. Following error is shown `gdb: No such file or directory`. what should I do??

Comment: Why not just use the regular lldb that comes with Xcode ?

Comment: I have never used lldb before. I just shifted to MAC a month ago so still learning

Comment: lldb is very similar to gdb and there are crib sheets which can help you with the differences in some commands - see e.g. http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html

Comment: But still if I you could help me with code signing issue as well, I would appreciate that.

Comment: Sorry - I don't know how to code sign a command line executable - I'm sure that there are plenty of other people here on SO who might be able to help though.

Comment: Thanks @Paul , for letting me know about the new tool

Comment: Try giving the absolute path of the `gdb` binary, i.e. `/usr/local/bin/gdb` if your homebrew instance is configured with the default prefix. If you still get the same error, make sure that gdb is linked by running `brew link gdb`. If you even still get an error, run `brew doctor` to check for relevant errors.

Comment: What makes you think you need to codesign this command line utility?

Comment: @trojanfoe Because the Darwin kernel will refuse `gdb` to control other processes otherwise. Mac OS X requires special rights for processes that wants to control or get information about other processes.

Comment: @Henrik Ah, so it's something particular to debuggers?

Comment: @trojanfoe It's particular to programs that somehow wants to control or influence other processes forcibly, which is something that a debugger most certainly wants to do. By codesigning the binary, you indicate to the system that special rights should be granted to the process. You can read about the workings of the Mach kernel here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/Mach/Mach.html